# How to highlight multiple text fragments on iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextview, highlighting

The past few days, I have been searching for a suitable solution to highlight multiple text fragments on iOS. The general idea is similar to how text highlighting works in Amazon's Kindle application.

I have experimented with `UITextView` as well as `UIWebView`, but I haven't find the right solution in terms of usability and performance.

The idea is simple. The user taps a sentence and the sentence is highlighted. When another sentence is tapped, that sentence is highlighted as well. The built-in solution for highlighting text is not suitable for this purpose. An important aspect of the solution is that the text needs to be styled, which is possible with `UITextView` since iOS 6.

My question is fairly general, that is, what are some viable approaches to implement this type of functionality? Are there any open source solutions that do what I describe?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to NSAttributedString on multiline UILabels. Starting from iOS 6 UILabels by default supports attributed strings without any modifications.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some text and some more %@", dynamicString]];

//Change background color to highlight a sentence, by giving sentence's range
[str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(sentenceStartIndex, sentenceLength)];

[label setAttributedText:str];
```

EDIT: It turns out UITextViews also support NSAttributedString I didn't try that, so you may replace UILabels with UITextViews.

Comment: My main question is not so much support for `NSAttributedString` but how to implement the ability to highlight multiple text fragments. As I mentioned in the question, I am aware that both `UILabel` and `UITextView` support `NSAttributedString` since iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) from Matt Thompson. It supports attributed strings, works all the way back to iOS 4, and is MIT licensed.

Comment: The deployment target for the project is iOS 6 so I can use `UILabel` and `UITextView`. The main questions is how to implement the ability to highlight multiple text fragments.

Comment: In that case guenis's answer should be fine for you - just add multiple attributes each with a different range.